# Carousel com posts do Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, slide

Olá, estou tentando aplicar o OWL-CAROUSEL em uma página com post personalizado. Quando faço no HTML normal, sem tags PHP, ele funciona super bem, mas se jogo no loop da wp_query ele não pega o plugin e lista os posts um embaixo do outro.

Veja o código abaixo:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">

        <?php
            $estrutura = new WP_Query('post_type=estrutura&orderby=post_status&order=DESC&showposts=-1');
            if($estrutura->have_posts()):while($estrutura->have_posts()): $estrutura->the_post();
        ?>

            <div class="item">
                <span>
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, array(501,301)); ?>
                    <!-- TAMANHO DA IMAGEM DEVE SER 1024x615 -->

                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                </span>

                <div>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php
            endwhile;
            endif;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>

        </div>
```

Como posso resolver esse problema? Lembrando que os scripts estão ok, todos sendo chamados, assim como os css's.

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Você está usando algum plugin wordpress pra chamar o owl-carousel ou está usando o plugin jquery direto?

Comment: Olá Ricardo, estou usando o plugin jquery direto.

Comment: E você está fazendo o enqueue do plugin jquery?

Comment: Sim, uso um outro plugin para navegação entre abas e funciona perfeitamente, além de outros scripts. Já tirei para ver se não era conflito entre eles, mas não é.

Comment: Como você comentou que funciona quando os dados são inseridos de forma manual acredito que o problema é a sua Query. Você pode fornecer o HTML gerado para este bloco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está nessa linha

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, array(501,301)); ?>
```

O correto seria usar a variável $post que é a variável global para o post.

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(501,301)); ?>
```